# List Test Cases when TEST OUTCOME = "Passed" and STATE is not = "Passed"

Tags: unit-testing, testing

How do I query and list all Test Case Runs whose OUTCOME = "Passed" and associated Test Case STATE is not = "Closed"?

What method do I use to identify passed Test Runs and associated Test Case not correctly updated to "Closed".

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to query on Runs using the work item queries.

So you'll need to resort to the API and create a script if some sort to do what you want to do.